# Brother laser jet on windows 8.1 keeps duplicating devices

Tags: windows-8.1, laser-printer, print-drivers

I have 4 laptops (HP 250 G2) and 4 Brother laser jet printers (HL-L2360DW) connected via USB. We sell tickets from them about 5 times a week. I cannot have them stationary so we have to bring them out and set them up. I do plug them in every time to the same USB plug (which shouldn't matter) and they are labeled so laptop 1 goes with printer 1 and so on.

After connecting everything I try to test print and once in a while to my surprise I cannot. So I look in devices and printers and see that sometimes the original printer is there and also shadow copies as well **example**: printer 1 (copy 1) & printer 1 (copy 2), which are somehow now the default printers. This fix is easy as i jut put the original as default and delete the copies (it is annoying though). Well I have had it where the original is not even there and the copies are. In that case I had to delete all brother software and re install from scratch. When I look at the ports I see USB000, USB001, USB002, USB003, USB004. I recently removed all printers and USB002 virtual port is still trying to be connected to brother printer 1 (copy 1) even though its not there.

I called Brother and they told me its because its windows 8 and its trying to install the printer using plug n play drivers. However they are no help and told me there is nothing they can do. Here is my question...

1. Can I stop the windows drivers from trying to do this sop that the printer keeps using the brother drivers?
2. Why is the printer just not staying the same, using the same ports and drivers?
3. Why can I sometimes not delete the ports that are no longer being used?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Your using the same port every time?

Comment: Yes the same physical USB port, however when it makes the copies it will add virtual printing ports.

Comment: I just unistalled all drivers and ports and rebooted, plugged in the printer and it found it, added printer, and added it to virtual printing port (USB001) even though (USB000) is there (might not be a big deal). I will Leave the Brother drivers downloaded from windows via plug n play and report back. Maybe they conflict for some reason.